# how to insert a row in the middle of a google spreadsheet

Tags: c#, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to insert a row into the middle of a google worksheet, however cannot find a way in the api documentation,

I cannot add a new row to the bottom as the program that consumes the spreadsheet data(not written by myself) simply ignores new rows added to the bottom.

anyone got any Ideas?

Comment: I'm not certain what you're asking for.  You want to shift several rows of data down a row and insert new data at the point where the shift started?  And lose a row off the bottom?

Comment: I have subsequently found out that the reason rows added to the bottom are being ignored is because I am adding rows to the spreadsheet but not the dataTable, this can be accessed in java but I am in c# so have not managed to figure out how to append a row to the datatable, modifications to cells that are already in the table work fine.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Spreadsheets API documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#adding_a_list_row)? There is a code snippet showing how to add a row to a worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code adds a row in the middle of the sheet:

```
function onOpen() {
  // get active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // create menu
  var menu = [{name: "Insert row ", functionName: "insertRow"}];

  // add to menu
  ss.addMenu("Insert", menu);  
}

function insertRow() {
  // get active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get first sheet
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[0];

  // determine number of rows (compensate for header)
  var rows = sh.getMaxRows();

  // insert row in the middle
  var middle = rows/2;
  sh.insertRows(middle);
}
```

1. It adds a menu item to the existing menu
2. Inserts a row in the middle of the sheet

See example file I've prepared: [add row in the middle](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdHJKV3lVUjRWNWdCMHNVZmpReUg4ZEE)

Comment: thanks for the answer, however since this is over two years old I gave up on the approach I was taking and will not be able to check your answer, I will mark it as accepted assuming your approach works since it looks like it would.